# How can I assign a value to a factory created simpletype object with python suds?

Tags: python, suds

I am working with the Cisco AXL Library using python suds. I am trying to call a function where I need to use a simpleType which is a special instance of string with a name restriction.

I create my object using a factory after parsing the WSDL succesfully:

```
 uuid = client.factory.create('ns0:XUUID')
```

This is an instance of the following XUUID object defined as follows in an XSD accompanying the WSDL:

```
 <xsd:simpleType name="XUUID">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
 <xsd:pattern value="\{........-....-....-....-............\}"/>
 </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
```

I want to now set the value of my uuid object, I tried all of the following with no success:

```
 uuid.setText('{900AAAAC-E454-0B7E-07FD-FD67D48FF50E}')
 uuid.set('{900AAAAC-E454-0B7E-07FD-FD67D48FF50E}')
```

It's clear that if this were a complexType with sub elements I would be able to set them, e.g. Person.name as in the suds Documentation. I can't figure out how to set the value for this object.

A print dir(uuid) of the object suggests that I may be going about this the wrong way.

```
 ['__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__getitem__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__keylist__', '__len__', '__metadata__', '__module__', '__printer__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__str__', '__unicode__']
```

In case I'm missing something basic or using suds completely wrong I'll explain a bit more of the context below.

I'm trying to call the following function from the WSDL:

```
 <operation name="getDevicePool">
   <input message="s0:getDevicePoolIn"/>
   <output message="s0:getDevicePoolOut"/>
 </operation>
 <message name="getDevicePoolIn">
   <part element="xsd1:getDevicePool" name="axlParams"/>
 </message>
```

It in turn references the following XSD elements:

```
 <xsd:element name='getDevicePool' type='axlapi:GetDevicePoolReq'></xsd:element>

 <xsd:complexType name='GetDevicePoolReq'>
 <xsd:sequence>
 <xsd:choice>
 <xsd:element name='name' type='axlapi:String100'></xsd:element>
 <xsd:element name='uuid' type='axlapi:XUUID'></xsd:element></xsd:choice>
 <xsd:element name='returnedTags' type='axlapi:RDevicePool' minOccurs='0'></xsd:element></xsd:sequence><xsd:attribute use='optional' name='sequence' type='xsd:unsignedLong'></xsd:attribute></xsd:complexType>
```

I tried an approach that worked well with another function from the WSDL:

```
 searchCriteria = {
         'callManagerGroupName':'Default'
 }
 devicePools = client.service.listDevicePool(searchCriteria)
```

But it didn't work here, I believe that it's because I need my UUID search string to be an XUUID type.

Answer (score 1):

Factory created objects are assigned values via object attributes. As an example from my own code:

```
>>> api = gcs.provider.get_api()
>>> client = api.get_client(api.API_DOMAIN)
>>> ident = client.factory.create('ns0:Identification')
>>> ident
(Identification){
   token = None
   user = None
   userPasswd = None
   oper = None
   operPasswd = None
   language = None
 }
>>> ident.user = 'Jeremy'
>>> ident
(Identification){
   token = None
   user = "Jeremy"
   userPasswd = None
   oper = None
   operPasswd = None
   language = None
 }
>>> setattr(ident, 'user', 'Lewis')
>>> ident
(Identification){
   token = None
   user = "Lewis"
   userPasswd = None
   oper = None
   operPasswd = None
   language = None
 }
```

You should be able to print the uuid object to see what the attribute is called, and then simply assign the value.